# Application To Pass Credentials To IE Authentication Popup

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, authentication, bho

This may have already been asked before but I did not see it anywhere.

*Essentially, what I'm looking to do is to have a small **C#** app (EDIT: or BHO) run and detect when IE (8 or higher) has been launched by a user.  Once it has launched, it needs to just sit there until it notices that an authentication challenge popup has been presented from within IE.  It would then hide the IE popup and present the user with a custom authentication popup.  This new popup would then pass the entered credentials back to IE for authentication*.

The app (or service) would cache the credentials and pass them to any further authentication popups received on a local Intranet.  So, this is a sort of custom quasi single sign-on solution.

Before people start suggesting changing settings in IE or on the server(s), please know that this is not possible.  The above explanation is **exactly** what we need to do.  I don't like it either.

We currently have a small in-house utility written in C++ (not .NET) that handles this exact identical behavior very successfully, but the source code is no longer available for fixes/upgrades.

Anything would be helpful.  Thanks all!

FYI - Just saw the first comment.  No, this is not a type of malware, pwd spoofer, or similar.  The employee gets a customized, company-logo'd credential pop-up to handle everything.  The purpose of it is to handle multiple different types of authentications (some are custom) specific to the varying sites within our Intranet.

Comment: sounds like a password spoofer...

Comment: Couldn't you just launch the process impersonating the user?

Comment: Some OS versions (like Win7) and some client-side setting will prevent such a tool from working correctly...

Comment: No.  Many workstations (non-AD) and logins are shared within certain facilities.  The user needs to manually type in their credentials.

We do have the utility working in Win7 beautifully.  Source code is no longer available for updates.

The information in _italics_ above is what needs to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found and decided upon a solution that is already working as a prototype (very limited prototype).  There's still much work to be done, but at least there is light at the end of the tunnel.  If I head a different route or receive better suggestions, I'll be sure to update this information.  For those whom might ever need something similar (doubtful), here's essentially what I'm doing.

Browser Helper Object

- Instantiated with each new IE instance.
- Registers with IE to receive events and new windows/controls being created.
- Hooks to receive descriptions of controls for logic to decide what to do.
- Handles to each authentication dialog windows or control.
- Handle to UIAutomation COM to inspect requesting server and realm.
- Multi-threaded support capable of thread blocking.
- Encrypted credentials cached in memory.
- .... and a whole lot more.

I hope that helps anyone needing to do the same.  Thanks all for any assistance you could give.  I guess everyone is as much of a noob with BHO's as I am.

EDIT 2/14:  This is indeed the answer.  I have the BHO working as desired.  There is still some very minor tweaking to accomplish.  (Actually, it's not that minor but it's working.)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this concept is **dangerous**. You are side-stepping the security model of the operating system to accomidate lazy users.

The other problem is that your architecture is fragmented. If you have tonnes of workstations across a big organization that don't use a proper platform for unified authentication (Such as AD / LDAP / Etc...) then you're going to run into a very-hard to maintain mess.

What you're doing here is plugging a hole, you're not fixing the crack. I **strongly** suggest you use this lack of source-code to keep "patching" the system together as the catalyst for change.

If you're so hell-bent on keeping the infrastructure as-is, then you should look to tested & proven software solutions to help aid in keeping things sane for your users.

Take a look at a FOSS Application [KeePass](http://keepass.info/). It will allow you to store your passwords securely (a problem your proposal would have to address anyway) and you can have your users store thier DB on a USB-Stick they keep with themselves at all times. They can log in once to thier KeePass DB and use the Auto-Type hotkeys to enter thier passwords in the various login boxes they are prompted for. This can work for more than just IE authentication requests, it can do all your applications.

The nice part about this is you can get people to use relatively strong passwords as they'll only have to remember the one (KeePass DB).

---

Ultimately you're going to run into issues trying to catch Authorization Challenges, even your existing solution is probably doing it in a very hack-ish way and you're going to find it increasingly hard in the future to continue this behaviour. This is mainly because it's an "IFFY AT BEST" solution, and will likely be made harder to execute as security matures.

Comment: I appreciate the comments and concerns (I expected many from others), but you're speaking to the choir here brother!  I have a 1,000 + 1 suggestions similar to your own, but no other options are possible.  It's simply a "must do" for me with no other way around it.

Comment: Then the only place I can point you is memory monitoring and keyboard emulation. But you're going to have to do your own research on that one. Challenges come from deep within the OS, they're generally related to a resource request. I suggest you start reading about the windows API documentation.

Comment: I appreciate the help anyways.  If I recall (very vaguely) something along the lines of instantiating an instance of SHDocVw.InternetExplorer consuming an already existing instance of IE launched by the user, then hooking into the COM events so as to raise whatever methods are needed.  That sounds familiar but I'm probably way way off.

Comment: Actually, I'm starting to think that this can be done with a BHO.  A BHO seems far more reasonable than a local app or service.  In fact, it solves several specific issues I couldn't get past.  I'm going to update the tags to include BHO (if one exists.)  I also updated the main description to include BHO.